# Не применяется внешний стиль CSS

Tags: html, css

Не работает css на html странице. Помогите пожалуйста разобраться почему.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel=“stylesheet” type=“text/css” href="style.css"/>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="script.js">
</script>

<div class="testClass">
    <input id="testArgument" type="text" value="1"/>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.testClass{
    position: center;
    font-size: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

-style.css не работает вообще с любыми селекторами, даже с глобальными.

-Google Chrome, ctrl+F5 не спасает.

-Все файлы лежат в одной папке и расширения у всех корректные.

-script.js работает.

-style.css открывается в браузере, если перейти к нему через отладку.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> <link rel=“stylesheet” type=“text/css” href="style.css"/>
> ```

Кавычки надо бы выпрямить и в дальнейшем смотреть, что копипастишь.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает. Как же я сгорел. ><

Comment: Это от копипаста =)